# Why does pca[:,1] have the shape of a one-dimensional array, instead of a matrix with one column?

Tags: python, numpy

`pca` is a 2x2 matrix. I want to multiply `pca[:,1]` by another 2x2 matrix like this: pca[:, 1].T * XtX, but numpy says 
"matrices are not aligned".

Why is `pca[:,1].shape` "`(2, )`"?

I know I could reshape but that looks dirty to me. Any ideas on how to cleanly work this around?

Comment: How are you performing the multiplication?

Comment: Like this: `pca[:, 1].T * XtX`

Comment: `XtX.shape` is `(2, 2)`.

Comment: `pca[:, 1]` is a row vector `pca[:, 1].T` is a column vector. `pca[:, 1] * XtX` works, `pca[:, 1].T * XtX` does not.

Comment: @Eduardo A shape of `(2,)` just means that it's a one-dimensional array of length `2`.  The trailing comma is an artifact of Python's tuple syntax.  Also, you should edit your first comment into the question since it's pretty crucial.

Comment: You are obviously expecting `pca[:, 1]` to have shape `(2, 1)`... You can get that either by indexing the columns with a single item slice, `pca[:, 1:]`, or by explicitly adding the extra dimension, `pca[:, 1:][:, np.newaxis]` or `pca[:, 1].reshape(-1, 1)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to form a *one-column submatrix* instead of extracting a *column*, select a one-element array of indices, instead of a single index: `pca(:, [1])` instead of `pca(:, 1)`.

```
import numpy as np
pca = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
pca[:, 1].shape     # returns (2,)
pca[:, [1]].shape   # returns (2, 1)
```

Here `pca[:, 1]` is `array([2, 4])` and `pca[:, [1]]` is `array([[2], [4]])`

---

The presence or absence of a dimension of length 1 is not an obstacle to matrix multiplication in your example. But it does matter in other situations, for example

```
np.dot(pca[:, 1], pca[0, :])       # result = 10
np.dot(pca[:, [1]], pca[[0], :])   # result = array([[2, 4], [4, 8]])
```